# How does parallel processing with pandas compare to dask?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

Hope this question is not too broad:

I am currently experimenting with dask (or parallel processing in general), and I can´t fully get my head around which benefits dask offers in terms of data processing. Especially compared to parallelizing data processes with pandas and multiprocessing library. My google skills wouldn´t reveal any fair comparison between both.

Is it just the ease of use or does it also offers better speed/memory efficacy?

Comment: From my point of view, if you want to use parallel processing on a single computer, use Pandas/Numba (or multiprocessing if you prefer). If you want to use on multiple nodes of a cluster, choose Dask.

Comment: You will probably be asked to pose a more specific question, as the current one could be considered requesting opinions rather than solutions.

Comment: It wouldn´t be an opinion if you tell the hard facts about the differences but I get you.

Comment: I agree that it's largely opinion-based. I usually go by [this pandas rule of thumb](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/): if data is stored locally and you have atleast 5x more RAM capacity, go for pandas.
If your dataset is stored locally, but is larger than the 5x mark, go for dask localcluster.
If data is on the cloud -- [dask deployments](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/how-to/deploy-dask-clusters.html) are a good idea.